# User Choice and loops vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to establish the logic for creating a navigation menu for a budget tracking system: it has 12 sheets for each budget line with 12 monthly tables per sheet.

The navigation menu is based on two combo boxes, one listing the sheets, and the other the names of the months - when a user selects where to go, the sheet and first cell in the chosen table activate.

What I'm looking for is a more effective way to organize this than writing 144 distinct if-then conditions accounting for every possible listindex combination the user might choose. The Select Case approach also works, but it is equally voluminous in scope...

I have been investigating using loops for the purpose - e.g. ListIndex values can be defined in a loop, but I'm coming up short on ideas for the overarching concept.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you make the list items the same as the sheet names, then no matter what is picked it can go right to it?  Then just loop through a range of cells until it finds the month, that is if there is a cell with the month name.  If you kept the sheet names relevant to the list items, you could even loop through the sheet names to generate the list items, that way sheets could be added and removed without affecting the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I set up a workbook with 12 worksheets one for each month.  Each worksheet has 12 tables on it.  When the user selects a worksheet from the dropdown (cboWorkSheets) the second drop down (cboTables) list is cleared and then all the table names from the selected worksheet is added to back to the list.

When a user selects a table name from cboTables the worksheet referenced by cboWorkSheets is searched for that table. The first cell in the table's databody range is then selected.

[image]

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cboTables_Change()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set ws = Worksheets(cboWorkSheets.Value)
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(cboTables.Value)
    ws.Activate
    tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub

Private Sub cboWorkSheets_Change()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject

    Set ws = Worksheets(cboWorkSheets.Value)
    cboTables.Clear
    For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects
        cboTables.AddItem tbl.Name
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    cboWorkSheets.List = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", "Sheet6", "Sheet7", "Sheet8", "Sheet9", "Sheet10", "Sheet11", "Sheet12")
End Sub
```

Comment: The tables are the months or the sheets are the months? Your original question says the tables, but this post says the sheets.

Comment: @great point  I'll redo it.   Ugh 10 minutes of my life wasted!!

Comment: @Tim Thanks again.  I like that much better.

Comment: Thomas, thank you for the effort you put into this. I've been trying to replicate it, but I'm not sure if you put the code in a module or in the user form? If in a module, there are variable definition problems, which you can solve by adding UserForm1 in front of the cbo's, but then the subscript falls out of range, which issue I had earlier...

Comment: You can download my test stub here: [User Choice and loops vba.xlsm](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nwcx0n6wc4n8bov/User%20Choice%20and%20loops%20vba.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a closer look.

Answer (score 1):

Doing the sheet selection is pretty straightforward. Just create an array that will hold the sheet name that corresponds to the ListIndex. Something like this

```
Dim myArray(11) As String
myArray(0) = "a"
myArray(1) = "b"
myArray(2) = "c"
...
myArray(10) = "k"
myArray(11) = "l"

Worksheets(myArray(ComboBox1.ListIndex)).Activate
```

If the person selects the 5th ComboBox element, sheet "e" would be activated.

Selecting the table cell is a bit more problematic since it depends on where on the sheet the tables are located. If they are spaced equidistantly apart, you can use a simple math formula. That is, if the January table starts at E7, Feb at E27, Mar at e47, then it is a simple matter of using the listindex to calculate the starting row. Eg:

```
Worksheets(myArray(ComboBox1.ListIndex)).Cells(7 + ComboBox2.ListIndex * 20, "E").Select
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Tim, thank you much! I took your approach, but the Worksheets line gave me grief. Eventually, i figured out why - set up the array and assign its elements to the combo box, this line needs to be specifically in the ComboBox_Change function: "With ComboBox1/Worksheets(.List(.ListIndex)).Activate/End With". Else you get an invalid property array index error.

Comment: Wait, you're saying that `Worksheets(ComboBox1.List(ComboBox1.ListIndex)).Activate` throws an error but `With ComboBox1 : Worksheets(.List(.ListIndex)).Activate:End With` does not? I'll have to test this because they should be exactly the same. Good to see that you were able to use the sheet names as values in to the combobox though. That simplifies things greatly.

Comment: It did, because I tried integrating it with the following code to assign the array to the combo box: 

With UserForm1.ComboBox1/
    .Clear/
    .List = sheets_array/
    .Style = fmStyleDropDownCombo/
    End With
It didn't make sense why it wouldn't work, but in the end I had to essentially come up with two WIth statements for the same thing...
Absolutely, using the sheet names as values is a big convenience. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

As general interest, this is the functional version of the code for a proof of concept file I built around @Tim's example, given above. Here goes:

In Module1:

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim sheets_array(0 To 2) As Variant

sheets_array(0) = "Sheet1"
sheets_array(1) = "Sheet2"
sheets_array(2) = "Sheet3"

With UserForm1.ComboBox1
    .Clear
    .List = sheets_array
    .Style = fmStyleDropDownCombo

    End With

    Call ComboBox2_Change

    UserForm1.Show
End Sub

Sub ComboBox2_Change()

Dim monthsarray(0 To 3) As Variant

monthsarray(0) = "April"
monthsarray(1) = "May"
monthsarray(2) = "June"

With UserForm1.ComboBox2
    .Clear
    .List = monthsarray
    .Style = fmStyleDropDownCombo
    End With

End Sub
```

In the UserForm1 code window:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

With UserForm1.ComboBox1
        Worksheets(.List(.ListIndex)).Activate
    End With
End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

With Worksheets(UserForm1.ComboBox1.ListIndex)
     .Select
     .Cells(7 + UserForm1.ComboBox2.ListIndex * 20, "E").Select
End With

End Sub
```

@Thomas Inzina, your solution is considerably more elegant and I hope I can think about programming at your level at some point.